# Call to a member function filterAccessiblePageIds() on string

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I want to get page content in my function. I am developing an extension for sending newsletters. My goal is to add page content in the mail body. I have created one new scheduler task and in this task I have added one field `pageId`. Now I want to get this page content in my custom scheduler task. So, I have writen below code.

SendNewslatters.php:

```php
$this->initTask();
            
$selectedGroup = (int)$this->group;
$pageId = (int)$this->pageId;
    
            
$renderer = $this->rendererUtility->getFluidRendererForTemplate(
              'typo3conf/ext/newslatters/Resources/Private/Templates/Subscribers/Mail/NewslaterMail.html',
              'html'
            );
    
$renderer->assign('pageId', $pageId);
$message = $renderer->render();
```

NewslaterMail.html:

```xml
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
    
    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{colPos: '0', pageUid: pageId}" />
    
</html>
```

Can you please help me here? How can I resolved this error?

Comment: I assume the title of your question is your error message. have you tried a debugging with `<f:debug title="all vars">{_all}</f:debug>` aside/ instead of your `f:cObject` call?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is, that you are not in frontend context and so the TSFE array is missing.

There a several approaches to instanciate the TSFE array (Be aware that it is not recommended to do so in the TYPO3 Documentation). But a good way is to use the nnHelper Extension:

https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/nnhelpers

You can either install the complete Extension or copy the `Tsfe` Class to your project.

In this solution i installed the Extension.

Your task should then look like this:

```
$pageId = (int)$this->pageId;

$tsfe = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\Nng\Nnhelpers\Utilities\Tsfe::class);
$tsfe->get($pageId);

$view = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView::class);
$view->setTemplateRootPaths([\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('EXT:newslatters/Resources/Private/Templates/Subscribers/Mail'));
$view->setTemplate('NewslaterMail');
$view->assign('pageId', $pageId);
$emailBody = $view->render();
```

In your template you should pass the pageUid directly and not as array, then you can access it via the current variable in Typoscript. You template should look like this:

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
  <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.newsletterContent" data="{pageId}" />
</html>
```

To render the content you can then use your own CONTENT lib like this:

```
lib.newsletterContent = CONTENT
lib.newsletterContent {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    pidInList.current = 1
  }
}
```

Be aware i used your typo newslater. Normally i would call it newsletter. But that only if someoneelse want to use this solution.